# Floated divs cant say next to each other because of border

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="col1">menu1</div>
    <div id="col2">menu2</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div>

#container
{
    width: 400px;
    background-color: green;
}

#col1
{
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    width: 48%;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}

#col2
{
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 52%;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZQpv/1/

this mightbe freaking simple, but I cant figure it out. When I dont have `border`, it works ok. But as soon as I add a `border`, the two divs cant stay next to each other. But I cant say anything like " 52% - 1px - 1px " to eliminate the border.

Comment: If you tell one to float right, the problem will become very obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add  `box-sizing: border-box;` to each col

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/4ZQpv/4/

Don't forget the prefixes for box-sizing.

Comment: actually, this is not working because of a missing "minus" letter

Answer (score 2):

just add `box-sizing` in each `div` it will set the border inside the `div`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZQpv/5/)

Comment: works, but somebody posted the solution faster, I cant cant accept it

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, a simple fix for this is to apply a margin of -1px to both #col1 & #col2.

```
#col1, #col2 {
     margin: -1px;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZQpv/3/

Comment: The many answers to this question highlights one of the things that can (sometimes) be enjoyable about CSS - there can be many ways to solve a given problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your container has an absolute width just use some math:

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZQpv/6/

```
#container
{
    width: 400px;
    background-color: green;
}

#col1
{
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    width: 190px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}

#col2
{
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 206px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```